# Was there a scene in Honey I Shrunk the Kids where Nick talked about the size of his database?

Tags: alternate-version, honey-i-shrunk-the-kids

While watching the first few minutes of *Honey, I Shrunk the Kids* on Netflix, I noticed that the movie was missing a scene that I remembered seeing when I was younger.

The scene was located at the very beginning of the film, and is one where Nick Szalinski is talking to someone, I think his sister in the kitchen, about how much memory their "database" had, and the number was really low, like 50 MB or something. But the scene was unintentionally funny because 50 MB, or whatever the quantity was, is a laughable size nowadays.

Was this scene removed from the movie? Is there an alternate release that contains it, like a Director's Cut or something? Or am I misremembering this?

Comment: I've been Googling, but still can't find it. This scene is apparently right up there with the Octopus scene in the Goonies.

Comment: Can someone at least confirm that they remember this scene? I know I'm not just imagining it because I had a friend bring it up a few years ago, too.

Answer (score 13):

There is a scene in the sequel, "Honey, I Blew Up the Kids", where he talks about losing all the information from his database at 38GB. You can find the script, on [springfieldspringfield](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=honey-i-blew-up-the-kid).

Could this be it, and you're confusing the two?

Comment: I've suggested an edit to clean up your answer. We discourage commenting as an answer; comment answers are usually deleted, but this stands well as an actual answer.

Comment: Congratulations, this answer is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4156/49).